# Add attachments to my Azure DevOps work item using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-devops

I have made an application that allows me to create a work item. When using my app you can enter the title, the priority, etc... But I want to include a new field where the users can enter their attachments like screenshots and then send all of these informations to Azure DevOps. I did everything exept attachments.

Here's for example some fields :

```js
const ticketData =
[
    { 
        op: 'add', 
        path: '/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild', 
        value: ''
    },
    { 
        op: 'add',
        path: '/fields/System.Title', 
        value: title 
    },
    { 
        op: 'add', 
        path: '/fields/Custom.00a17f02-70c7-4683-a6d4-c607f4b0a243', 
        value: priorite 
    },
    { 
        op: 'add', 
        path: '/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps', 
        value: reproSteps 
    },
    { 
        op: 'add', 
        path: '/fields/Criticité', 
        value: criticite 
    },
    { 
        op: 'add', 
        path: '/fields/Custom.Etatattendu', 
        value: etatAttendu 
    }, 
    { 
        op: 'add',
        path: '/fields/Custom.Etatobservable', 
        value: etatObservable 
    }, 
    { 
        op: 'add', 
        path: '/fields/Custom.Affectedversion', 
        value: affectedVersion 
    }, 
    { 
        op: 'add', 
        path: '/fields/Custom.Environnement', 
        value: environnement 
    }, 
    { 
        op: 'add', 
        path: '/fields/Custom.Titredulot', 
        value: titredulot
    }, 
    { 
        op: 'add', 
        path: '/fields/Custom.PutonCreation', 
        value: { displayName: accounts[0].name }
    }
]
```